# Set Varnish headers conditionally based on client.ip

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

How would I use client.ip as a conditional in setting headers in the fetch section of a Varnish 3.0 VCL? I have some troubleshooting headers that I like to set to solve caching issues, however, I don't want them publicly visible. I'd love to be able to whitelist the headers for my ip address only.

Is there any way to access client.ip in _fetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can best set all troubleshooting headers in you _recv without any conditions and remove them in you vcl deliver. this way you dont need to add the same ip check on every conditional header

if you want to use an ip range you can use the following code

```
acl debug {
"your ip adress1";
"you ip adress 2";
}
```

in you vcl_recv

```
if (!client.ip ~ debug) {
set req.http.x-debug = "debug";
}
```

in you vcl_deliver

```
if(!req.htt.x-debug){
remove resp.http.debugheader1;
remove resp.http.debugheader2;
}
```

Comment: The key was using an ACL to set a debug header and using that as a conditional. Thanks for getting me on the right track.